# Grace period for suggested edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

As far as I know, the grace period for edits is 5 minutes, and it doesn't matter if it's a normal or a suggested edit.

I proposed an edit for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/684755/what-are-these-notches-on-the-side-of-the-pci-express-connector) and later on, well past the 5 minutes, I noticed I didn't correct a spelling mistake on the title.

Nonetheless, I clicked on *edit* and my suggestion summary was intact and I assumed that fixing the title wouldn't count as another suggestion. Is it right? Did I only propose one edit or was it two suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[You suggested a single edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/180114).

Comment: So, the grace period ends after the first review? Not the regular 5 minutes, is it flexible?

Comment: @brasofilo: I'm not sure if there would have been 2 suggestions after a certain period of time. But once a suggested edit was reviewed, another edit on the same post would lead to a new suggested edit.

Comment: That's clear. My doubt is if there is such a thing as a 30 minutes grace period, which apparently is true.

Comment: @brasofilo: I would assume it's flexible. As long as there is a pending edit, any further edit will be merged into it.